# Equipping Notepad with Spell Check (as you type) feature -- Best choice available?

Tags: notepad, spell-checking

I don't need any alternative text editor with bundle of features. I just want my text to be checked in Notepad (as I type) for any spelling mistake. What is the best choice available? Thanks in advance.

Comment: not programming related?

Answer (score 3):

I asked Google and Google gave me some links. http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,68576-page,1-c,downloads/description.html looks like what you need. It is free, it is small, and it does not have any extra features that you do not need.